# while converting video set variable $process as 1 with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, codeigniter-3

In this video is converted and uploaded to server and DB, While conversion process going I want to set one variable "$process" as 1. And I want to upload to DB and after conversion completed $success variable become 1. How to do this.

### conversion.php

```
echo "I am in conversion process -----";
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$path." -vcodec libx264 ".$path_str."> /dev/null 2>&1 &");  
$convertedFile = basename($path_str);
                    
echo "I am in conversion process2 -----";
                    
exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$path.' 2>&1', $path_str,$return);
                                             
$sql = "INSERT INTO upload (convertedFile,uploadedFile,videoLength,thumbnail,userId,status)   VALUES('$convertedFile','$filename','$length','$thumb','$userId','$return')";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
$sql = "select * from conversion where uploadedFile='$convertedFile'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$success = ($return == 1)?1:0;
$error   = ($return == 0)?1:0;
if(!$result){ 
    $q = "UPDATE conversion  SET success = '$success' , error = '$error' WHERE uploadedFile = '$convertedFile'"; 
}
else {
 $q = "INSERT INTO conversion (uploadedFile,process,error,success)   VALUES('$convertedFile','0','$error','$success')";
}
mysql_query($q) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` and make use of `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @apokryfos   While conversion process takes place set variable $process as 1. After update it will change as 0.

Comment: That's the desired behaviour which is also apparent in the code. I asked what the problem is. Is the code above not working?

Comment: @apokryfos after update that value in DB I want to show message as "your video is under conversion process, please wait".

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here. What's the exact user experience you're after, where does the video come from and where should the user see the message you're saying?

Comment: @apokryfos In the above code just want to set that $process variable while video converting. If you help to do that I will do the further steps about message and other...

Comment: @Kevin check my answer i think it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo "I am in conversion process -----";

// insert before process start

```
$q = "INSERT INTO conversion (process) VALUES ('0')";
```

// execute insert query

```
 $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($q);
```

remove else part and change update query

// update value after process complete

```
$q = "UPDATE conversion  SET success = '$success' , error = '$error', uploadedFile = '$convertedFile' where id='$lastid'";
```

Comment: Insertion before process start not working. Directly conversion process started. i checked DB. How to insert before. If it is done half of my problem soleved

Comment: insert before 
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$path." -vcodec libx264 ".$path_str."> /dev/null 2>&1 &");  
$convertedFile = basename($path_str);

Comment: `echo "I am in conversion process -----";
      $convertedFile = basename($path_str);
      $q = "INSERT INTO conversion (uploadedFile,process,error,success)   VALUES('$convertedFile','1','0','0')";
      //exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$path." -vcodec libx264 ".$path_str."> /dev/null 2>&1 &");  
      exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$path." -vcodec libx264 ".$path_str, $return);  
      
      
      echo "I am in conversion process2 -----";
      
      exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$path.' 2>&1', $path_str,$return);` 
I have done like this. But not working.

Comment: are you executing query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154893/discussion-between-kevin-and-ahmed-ginani).